# Multivariate linear regression in excel 2003

Tags: excel-2003

Is this feature in excel 2003? I can't seem to find any kind of data analysis through the menu at all. Perhaps I need to make a chart first?
http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Multiple+Regression+excel+2003&aq=f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [Analysis Toolpak](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/load-the-analysis-toolpak-HP001127724.aspx) (or activate it if it's already loaded) a to have access to the regression tool.

Here is a [pdf](http://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~pecklund/ExcelReview/Use%20Excel%202007%20Regression.pdf) that runs you through an example.

Comment: The IT fellow that I work with gave me these exact directions, it is now present in the Tools menu. Thank you for your help!